# Flutter how to show list from firebase in list view

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting a list from firebase in a `StreamBuilder` widget. I want to show it in a `ListView` widget but it doesn't work.

[image]

Here is my code:

```dart
final current = document.data as Map<String, dynamic>;
final activities = current["activities"] as List;
List titles = activities.map((e) => e["title"]).toList();
List av = activities.map((e) => e["days"]).toList();

ListView.builder(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemCount: av.elementAt(i).length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(av.elementAt(i)[0][index]),
    );
  },
),
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

All the variables such as these

```
final current = document.data as Map<String, dynamic>;
final activities = current["activities"] as List;
List titles = activities.map((e) => e["title"]).toList();
List av = activities.map((e) => e["days"]).toList();
```

needs to be loaded once the data from firestore is recieved.
So, following would be your code:

```
 StreamBuilder(
            stream: _firestoreStream, //use .snapshot() to get data
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                final current = snapshot.data as Map<String, dynamic>;
                final activities = current["activities"] as List;
                List titles = activities.map((e) => e["title"]).toList();
                List av = activities.map((e) => e["days"]).toList();

                return ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: av.elementAt(i).length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(av.elementAt(i)[0][index]),
                    );
                  },
                );
              } else {
                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
            }),
```